# Is adding a bot to a Telegram channel broken after update to version 4.1?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I can't seem to add a bot to a channel after the latest update to Telegram (to version 4.1).

I can only select administrators from the channel members and I can only add a channel member from my phone contacts. Search for the bot (in this case: @vote) gives empty results.

Comment: check the settings button added to the channel's info page.

Comment: @tashakori I tried that, clicked Administrators. It doesn't let me add the bot there - just to select from the members that are already in the channel.

Comment: In that page(activity) you can choose from the users of channel, or hit the search icon and type the bot's name

Comment: @tashakori I tried to add the bot ("@vote") to the channel. I tried searching for it. It doesn't allow me to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Telegram has intoduced levels of access for Channel admins in the version 4.1.

If  you are creator of the channel, you can do everything with your channel, otherwise tell the creator of the channel to give you the required permissions. In your case, the title of permission is: "can add admins"

Comment: I am the creator and owner of the channel. It still doesn't allow me to add the bot to the channel. In fact, I did it before (before the last update) and it worked with no problem. Note that I'm referring to a _channel_, not a group.

Comment: I have checked just now, and @votebot is one of my channels admins now! What error have you got?

Comment: I checked again - it doesn't allow me to add a bot. I don't get an error - just an empty screen. I tried both in the Android app (updated to the latest version) and the web (which is completely outdated, so I wasn't really expecting it to work from there). Are you using the iPhone app perhaps?

Comment: No, I tested on android and desktop. Only thing that i can think of is that you don't type the name of bot completely. (You should type"bot" suffix too. E.g. @votebot)

Comment: Adding `@votebot` worked but it added a different bot than the one I was using - `@vote`. It seems that the one I was using is simply bugged or not updated. Accepting your answer though since it's kind of correct (and for the effort) - thanks.